# Issue with redirecting to pages in a virtual Web Forms application deployed in IIS within an MVC application?

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, webforms

I have an MVC application deployed in IIS 10, within a subfolder I have a virtual application that is a Web Forms application.

The MVC application creates a cookie and then uses Response.Redirect to navigate to the Web Forms application signin page.

The Web Forms application then logs the user in based on information in the cookie, it then loads a profile page for the user. The signin page uses Server.Transfer to load the profile page. I had to use Server.Transfer otherwise I was getting the 'too many redirects' error.

The issue occurs when I try and click a button to navigate to another page once I'm at the profile page.

When the profile page is loaded I have the following URL:

*http://localhost:8090/WebFormsApplicationName/signin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWebFormsApplicationName%2fprofileview.aspx*

On this page I have a button that should enable me to edit the users profile, when I click on this button I see the following URL:

*http://localhost:8090/WebFormsApplicationName/signin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWebFormsApplicationName%2fprofileedit.aspx*

Although the URL changes the profile page being shown does not change. The application does not load the profile edit page??

I have used different methods of redirecting to the profile edit page. For example *PostBackURL* within a LinkButton, also a *hyperlink* and also a *button with a button click event* defined. None of the methods differ in the page response.

As a test I tried putting http://www.google.com as the redirect location and it works fine (even though google shows a page saying you can't post to google - which is expected). So the issue seems to be loading pages on the local domain.

If I run the MVC application within Visual Studio and put a breakpoint on the command that loads the Web Forms signin page and then run the Web Forms application in a separate instance of Visual Studio I can get to the profile page, click on the button and successfully load the profile edit page.

Bearing this in mind I am now thinking it may be IIS related because this behaviour is only being exhibited when running from IIS. I would appreciate any help please. I have spent the last 3 days trying to resolve this, thank you.

Comment: Further update: Today I will be debugging the applications while they are running in IIS, should benefit me 2 fold. I have never debugged an application running in IIS and hopefully it will bring me closer to a solution!